# Need to recursively find all filenames containing a colon and replace the colon with a dash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

I have a directory 'main' containing many sub-directories and in some of these sub-directories I have filenames that contain a colon. I uploaded the 'main' directory to a GitHub repository from Linux, but I ran into problem when I then tried to pull from this repository on a Windows machine, as Windows doesn't allow colons in filenames.

How can I recursively find all filenames with a colon in the 'main' directory using the Linux terminal, and then replace the colon with a, say, a dash (-) character?

Answer (score 8):

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*:*" -exec rename -n 's/:/-/g' {} +
```

(If this command doesn't work for you, see the Compatibility Note at the end of this answer.)

This is a basic safe version that only prints what would happen. To make it actually happen get rid of `-n` option.

It would work without `-name "*:*"` but it's good to let `find` pass only the filenames that should be changed because this makes the whole command faster.

It works like this:

- `find` finds...

  - ...in the `/path/to/directory` dir...
  - ...all files (`-type f`)...
  - ...with matching names (`-name "*:*"`),...
  - ...then executes `rename` (multiple times if needed)...
  - ...with the pattern to replace `:` by `-`...
  - ...on all the files found, multiple files at once (`{} +`).

Notes:

- The command doesn't rename directories and this is by design.
- Renaming may not work with some unusual characters in the filename (e.g. newline). Most certainly you have no such filenames there so this is rather a formal note.

---

#### Compatibility Note

The solution uses Perl script `rename` from `rename` package available on Debian, Ubuntu. Other distros may have `rename` from `util-linux`.

[This manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) suggests that the solution for non-Perl `rename` should be:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*:*" -execdir rename -n ':' '-' {} +
```

(Again, remove `-n` if it looks right.) I haven't tested this though. I think it will replace only the first colon in a filename. A workaround is to repeat the command (without `-n`, with `-v`) until there are no colons left.

Alternatively you can obtain the Perl script from an archive available on [this site](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename/rename.PL) (currently `File-Rename-0.20.tar.gz`, the script is named `rename.PL`). See also [this question](https://superuser.com/q/302380/432690).

Comment: ..hmmm..I'm getting an error when I enter the command - rename: not enough arguments. This is with and without the -n option. Any ideas why its not working?

Comment: I am using Fedora by the way if that makes a difference.

Comment: @eurocoder Please check the alternative command near the end of the edited answer, it may work for you.